# OCaml code consecutive list creation simple code

Tags: ocaml

I have been trying one of the problems on 99 OCaml problems where you have to a have a list of all consecutive numbers in a list such as `[2;3;4;4;5;6;6;6]` -> `[[2];[3];[4;4];[5];[6;6;6]]`

```
let rec tail = function
  | [] -> []
  | [x] -> [x]
  | x::xs -> tail xs;;

let pack lst =
  let rec aux current acc = function
    | [] -> current
    | [x] -> if (tail acc) = x then (x::acc)::current 
             else [x]::current
    | x::y::xs -> if (x=y) then aux current (x::acc) (y::xs) 
                  else aux (acc::current) [] (y::xs)
  in
  aux [] [] lst;;
```

When i run this i get the error

```
Error: This expression has type 'a list
but an expression was expected of type 'a list list
The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list
```

I was wondering what the problem is?

Comment: `(tail acc)=x` seems to be the culprit

Comment: Ahh yes of course thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As Bergi pointed out `(tail acc)=x` is the problem. `tail` returns `'a list` so `x` must also be of type `'a list`.  The following `x::acc` then infers that `acc` must be of type `'a list list`. But `tail acc` infers `acc` as `'a list`.

At this point OCaml can't unify the types of `'a list list` and `'a list` and gives the error you see.